# How many different strings can be made using the letters of ABBCCCDDDDEEEFF such that all the letters D must appear before all of letters F?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

There are all together $15$ letters. $1$ A, $2$ B's, $3$ C's, $4$ D's, $3$ E's and $2$ F's.

I only know that the total different strings that can be made from those $15$ letters is $$\frac{15!}{1!2!3!4!3!2!} = 378,378,000$$ and I'm stuck there.

These are the methods that I'm using following my lecture's eg but I actually don't understand the reasoning behind them.

Method1 :  15c1 ( for the A) x 14c2 (for the Bs) x 12c3 (for the Cs) x 9c3 (for the Es) x 1 (no. of ways to place Ds and Fs) and I would get 25,225,200.

Method2:  I could use 15p9/ (2!3!3!1!) to get 25,225,200

As mentioned, I'm just blindly following the method but I dun understand them. Please explain them if you could. Thanks!

Comment: Are there 4 or 3 Ds?

Comment: There is a discrepancy between your title and your question.  I assume you meant to place $4$ D's in the title.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: There are Four Ds

Answer (score 2):

First choose the places for the Ds and Fs. There are $$\binom{15}6$$ ways to do this. Put these letters in the correct order.

Then you can put the remainding letters at will, and there are
$$\frac{9!}{1!2!3!3!}$$
ways to do this.

Multiply both results.

Comment: I get the same ans using other method although I'm just blindly following the eg given in the lecture, thanks for reaffirming me. Anyway, could you tell me why is it that we can just use 15c6 to place the Ds and Fs? I thought I would have to fix the Ds and Fs position so that Ds is in front of Fs. Because there isn't any order in 15c6 right?

Comment: Because once we pick our six positions where we put the Ds and Fs (15 choose 6 choices here), there is only one way to arrange the Ds and Fs, namely DDDDFF

Answer (score 2):

There are six letters that are either a $D$ or an $F$.
A string is acceptable if the last two of the six are $F$s.
So only one in every $6\choose2$ of the 378378000 are acceptable.